# Background Color Changer working explanation needed using array of colors

Tags: reactjs

```js
function bgChanger() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState('white');
  const changeColor = () => {
    const colors = ['red', 'lightblue','green', 'pink', 'violet', 'yellow', 'orange', 'torquoise']
    var Scolor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    setColor(Scolor);
  }
```

I'm a beginner in React and this is my 2nd project.

I wanted to make a random color changer using react so i used an array to store the colors.
Used a variable Scolor (Select Color) which stores the randomized color from the array. But I didnt quite understand the how to do it, so I just copied a code snippet from Stackoverflow.
But now I'm unable to understand the code and I need assistance to understand why do we use Math.floor & multitply length of colors array with Math.Random

Answer (score 0):

Math.random() return random value less then 1. like 0.2154, 0.6524.to display different color firstly i need a random number which should not greater then colors length. if i multiply Math.random() with colors length i will always get a number which is smaller then colors length. here is working code -

```
import { useState } from "react";

const colors = [
  "red",
  "lightblue",
  "green",
  "pink",
  "violet",
  "yellow",
  "orange",
  "torquoise",
];
const App = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState(colors[0]);
  
  const setRandomColor = () => {
    setColor(colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: color, height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }}>
      <button onClick={setRandomColor}>Change Color</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Math.floor() in typescript return the rounded number to the nearest down integer.
for example 4.89411570149498 once called the Math.floor() it will return
number: 4

You can check this code with the console.logs for the better understanding.

```
const changeColor = () => { 
  const colors = ['red', 'lightblue','green', 'pink', 'violet', 'yellow', 'orange', 'torquoise'] 
  const tt = Math.random() * 7
  console.log(tt)
  console.log(Math.floor(tt))
  var Scolor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]; 
  console.log(Scolor)
}

changeColor()
```

And Math.random() will generate a number like this: 0.8990969814246639